# How can I plot out url encoded content in node.js?

Tags: objective-c, node.js, logging, get, decode

I try to plot out the JSON that is encoded, but it does not work.

This is how I encoding on server side in iOS:

```
NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[json bytes] length:[json length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is how I try to log out content:

```
app.get('/:tableName', function(req, res) {
var schema = require('./schema/' + req.param('tableName'));
console.log('req.query ' + req.query);
```

and this is what I see now in terminal:

```
req.query [object Object]
GET /System?%7B%0A%0A%7D 200 161ms - 2b
```

UPDATE

Thanks your answer, maybe could you say me, how can I change the order of the two lines, first the line of the resource second line the query? Is it a way to write out in a colored way the second line too?

Now top lines look like these:

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx.mongolab.com:xxx/db1');
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
var inspect = require('util').inspect;
```

[image]

UPDATE

now I use for colored formatting and write log at request:

`app.use(morgan({format: 'dev', immediate: true }));`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `util.inspect()`[1] on the variable directly to get a human readable representation of the object, or you can use `console.dir()`[2] on the variable.

[1]

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

app.get('/:tableName', function(req, res) {
  var schema = require('./schema/' + req.param('tableName'));
  console.log('req.query ' + inspect(req.query));
});
```

[2]

```
app.get('/:tableName', function(req, res) {
  var schema = require('./schema/' + req.param('tableName'));
  console.dir(req.query);
})
```

Comment: By default morgan logs output when the response is finished. Otherwise you have to `app.use(morgan({ immediate: true }));` to get it to log on request instead.

Comment: thanks, I found other options here: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/a3ccdc0bf2d583971c21c7d1c21a5b25b26726b0/index.js